# Running maven plugins on artifact's pom file

Tags: java, maven

Many of maven's plugins run on the current project's `pom.xml` file.

Sometimes I need to run a certain plugin on an artifact I downloaded from the repository.

For instance I'm downloading `sparkjava` using `dependency:get` like that:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.4
```

I would like then download all `sparkjava`'s dependencies sources using `dependency:sources` like that:

```
mvn dependency:sources -Dartifact com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.4
```

Or even better, run `dependency:sources` directly on the artifact:

```
mvn dependency:sources -DinputPom=locationToRepository/com/sparkjava/2.5.4/spark-core-2.5.4.pom
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

The maven dependency plugin sources goal tells Maven to resolve all dependencies and their source attachments, and displays the version.
You can specifically includes or excludes artifacts by using optional parameters. See the [maven dependency plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html).

Comment: It doesn't work since the plugin requires a POM file. Also according to the documentation it already gets all artifacts that are dependencies of the project. I'm getting this error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:sources (default-cli): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directo
ry (/home/alex). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]